# Random Forest test data

Tags: r, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I am trying to use random Forest model on my data set which has 4679 observations and 13 variables.

I am using the random forest model to predict is a part will fail or not.

On the total 4679 observations, I have 66 observation with my target variable as NA. I wanted to predict if this 66 part will fail or not.

SO, I decided to split my train data into first 4613 as my train data and rest 66 rows as my test data.

```
train<- Imputed_data[1:4613, ] 
test <- Imputed_data[4614:4679, ]
```

I then used the below code for my random forest

```
fit<- randomForest(claim.Qty.Accepted~., data=train, na.action=na.exclude)
```

The training confusion matrix I received was clear. 
I tried the same to predict my test with the following piece of code

```
#Prediction for test set
p2 <- predict(fit, test)
head(p2)
head(test$claim.Qty.Accepted)
caret::confusionMatrix(p2, test$claim.Qty.Accepted)
```

the confusion matrix was 0 with both the classes of Yes and No.

I later saved the predicted value p2 in the form of data frame like below; in the table i could see that all the 66 entries have Yes and No classes.

`t2<- data.frame(p2)`

I am confused why, the confusion matrix didn't show me the results of prediction? Also is this a right approach I am following to predict my test result? Any lead would be helpful, since i am new in the field.

Comment: I think you have some misconceptions about how random forests work.  In general, when building an RF model, you include _all_ data, unless it represents a large outlier.  For your specific case, you probably should have included the 66 points with `NA` responses, and just assigned the mean/median response to those 66 points.  Furthermore, you _do not_ cross validate a random forest by hand.  Rather, the cross validation process happens implicitly when the forest is being built.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But including the 66 points with NA throws me a error that missing values can not be present in a output variable y. on the other hand, if i am not wrong, mean mode imputations are generally done to our input variable ? not to output

Comment: I guess you didn't read my entire comment.  I never suggested just adding those 66 points with an `NA` response, I said to use the mean/median response value in place of the `NA` values.  Later, if you want to predict responses for the 66 points using your RF model, it is pretty easy to do that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could you suggest me how i could do that ?

Comment: Just replace `NA` with the median value, then run random forests.  Then, take the return value from that (a random forest object), and use it to predict a response for the 66 points.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok wil try doing it this way

Comment: @Mikz, as far as I can see, you don't know the answer for your test/production dataset, so you can't calculate a confusion matrix!